# Rails 4 - how to populate checkboxes from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, hash

I have following hash:

```
CAR_SERVICE = {"Service 1" => 0,
               ...
               "Service 43" => 33}
```

and I need to take the data from the hash and display them into 34 checkboxes. Then, I have a database table with this structure:

```
car_services:
- id
- car_id
- service_number # here goes the value (0 to 33) from the hash
```

Is there a method or a helper that would take this hash and "display it in checkboxes" and after a user save them, then would automatically checked the respective ones (the ones the a user checked)?

Thank you.

PS: There's a `select` helper that do that (but I need "the same" functionality for checkboxes):

```
  <%= f.select :status, CAR_STATUS, {}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your template where you are generating the list of checkboxes - in the end - this is the part of your code you're asking help for

Comment: I don't have it - I mean, I could do that with a loop, but I am just seeking if there's a more efficient way to do that (like the `f.select` snippet for example).

Comment: @user984621 I think no direct helper, rather you need to loop on it...

Comment: I got [this](http://makandracards.com/makandra/871-manipulate-an-array-attribute-using-multiple-check-boxes) looping way...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in the looping way

Just a example modify accordingly

```
<div class="row">
  <label for="car_ids[]">Car name:</label>
  <% for car in Car.find(:all) do %>
  <br><%= check_box_tag 'car_ids[]', car.id,
          @model.car_ids.include?(car.id) %>
  <%= car.name.humanize %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Hope this helps